# Need to automatelist partitioning to a new table in rds postgres 12.10

Tags: database, postgresql, amazon-rds, partitioning, pg

Can someone guide to automate LIST partitioning to a new table in rds postgres v12.10. At runtime I can get different values of the partition key. How can U automate this

Comment: What about the PostgreSQL manual?

Comment: Is this really your last resort after coming up blank with the rest of the internet?

Comment: not able to find a single resource to automate list partitioning in rds

Comment: Just run a cron job and you’re done. Many other comparable options available as well

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you want partitions to be created as you insert data. You cannot do that in PostgreSQL. Perhaps an ugly workaround like in [this article](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/automatic-partition-creation-in-postgresql/) can help: Have a trigger that creates the target table if it does not yet exist and notifies a special worker process that attaches the newly created table as a partition.